# v-if in <header> of webpage in vue fram

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want if variable `sudoUser` is true, add a specific link to header
I try to do that with something like this

```
<link v-if="sudoUser" somelink </link>
```

But `v-if` not check if it in header section. If I move that the body section, this code work fine.
I don't want to dynamical load that after page loading finish.
How should I us if condition in header section of webpage?

Comment: Vue.js questions are highly version specific, please only tag the version your app actually uses

Comment: You may want to look into [@vueuse/head](https://github.com/vueuse/head), can be used with either Vue 2 or Vue 3